# Open URLs in a new tab from command line

Tags: tabs, command-line-interface, chromium

You can ask a running Firefox instance to open an URL in a new tab by executing the command:

```
firefox -new-tab http://stackoverflow.com
```

How do you accomplish the same in Chromium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try.

```
chromium-browser http://stackoverflow.com
```